# Angular2: When doing two-way binding, do I need to explicitly use an EventEmitter?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Suppose that I have a Kitchen class that looks like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <kitchen [(kitchenLunch)]=lunch></kitchen>  
    `
})
export class House {

    private lunch: Lunch;

}
```

The House component:

- Contains a sub-component `Kitchen`
- The house has a dataModel containing some state.
- The house has setup two-way binding with the kitchen on the dataModel
- When the house or kitchen changes the dataModel, the changes should appear in both places.

My question is on the syntax of the `@Output` in the Kitchen.  This is currently what I am using:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kitchen',
    template: '...'
})
export class Kitchen {

    @Input  
    private kitchenLunch: Lunch;

    @Output 
    private kitchenLunchChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

}
```

This currently works as I expect.  Whenever I update the kitchenLunch in the `Kitchen` component, I do the following:

```
this.kitchenLunch = **Something**
this.kitchenDataModelChange.next(this.kitchenDataModel);
```

However, this seems slightly redundant.  What I would really like to do is shorten the Kitchen class to do something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kitchen',
    template: '...'
})
export class Kitchen {

    @Input  
    @Output 
    private kitchenLunch: Lunch;

}
```

Then when I update kitchenLunch, I would like to just do this:

```
this.kitchenLunch = **Something**
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to have a private member be an input & output?
2. Can you have an @Output that is not an EventEmitter?
3. Is there some short hand that I can/should use here?
4. It looks like the `@Output` must be named the same as the input plus `Change`.  In this case `kitchenLunch + Change`.  I figured this out by trial and error.  Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) don't know but I guess it works. Should be easy to find out.

2) no

3) no

4) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

> [(ngModel)] is a specific example of a more general pattern in which
>   Angular "de-sugars" the [(x)] syntax into an x input property for
>   property binding and an xChange output property for event binding.
>   Angular constructs the event property binding's template statement by
>   appending =$event to the literal string of the template expression.
>
> [(x)]="e" <==> [x]="e" (xChange)="e=$event"
>
> We can write a two-way binding directive of our own to exploit this
>   behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `Ouput` `EventEmitter` with two-way binding.

However, it's recommended to use one-way binding together with `EventEmitter` because it may give you better performance. Briefly, it reduces amount of change detection **Angular 2** should perform.

More details here http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/